# MySQL query efficiency ( use of MIN)

Tags: mysql

Anyone can help me to optimize this query? I am new on Stackoverflow and appreciate any idea.

--

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(g2.serialid)) as countResult
from g2table g2 INNER JOIN
     ((SELECT p.serialid AS serialid, p.created as created, MIN(g.starttime) AS firstuse
       FROM gtable g INNER JOIN
            ptable p
            ON g.serialid = p.serialid
       WHERE  (p.created < '2015-05-22')
       GROUP BY p.serialid
      ) ) AS firstuseset
     ON g2.serialid = firstuseset.serialid
 WHERE (firstuseset.firstuse < '2015-05-22') AND
       ((g2.starttime > '2015-05-22') AND (g2.starttime < '2015-05-23'))
```

Comment: You should work on writing your queries so you (and other people) and read them.  Then worry about performance.  It would help your question a lot if you (1) described what the query is supposed to do; (2) provided sample data; (3) provided desired results.  A SQL Fiddle is also helpful.

Comment: And for any question that has the word 'optimise' in it, you should be including table definitions, index definitions, and the output of `explain`

Comment: Aside from any other problems with this query, be aware that p.created is indeterminate

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. The purpose of this query is to find the device which is activated(created) before a certain day and first time used(starttime) before a certain day. The table g and g2 is log table for the device and p is the device table.

Comment: Thank you, pala. All fields are indexed. output of "explain" will be posted ASAP I went to office.

Comment: Thank you, Strawberry. Would you please explain what you mean "indeterminate"?

Comment: @mingwork He means if there are multiple rows with the same `serialid` but different `created`, when you do `GROUP BY serialid` it's unpredictable which one will be returned -- it won't necessarily be the one with the minimum `starttime`.

Comment: explain result:  id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra; 1, primary, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables; 2 DERIVED, p, range, "PRIMARY, created", created, 9, null , 295778, "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort"; 2, DERIVED, g, ref, "PRIMARY, serialid", serialid, 74, p.serialid, 7, Using index

Answer (score 0):

In order to optimize `MIN(g.starttime)`, I think you need a composite index on `(serialid, starttime)` in `gtable`:

```
CREATE INDEX serial_starttime on gtable (serialid, starttime);
```

An index on `created` in `ptable` will optimize the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar. I have composite index (serialid, starttime, serverid) and created is also indexed. But still the query takes 3 minutes to get results from not so big table(less than 1G).